# html5 app code for iPhone - do you know some good resources?

Tags: iphone, html

do you know any example of an HTML5 app that you can use to select some photos and send them to a server? I am looking for some good resources for learning HTML5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out HTML5 Boilerplate Mobile:

http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile